# How do I simplify my output in the matrix

Tags: python, matrix

my output is giving 0.00e+00 instead of the whole numbers. I think it's becuase the y of the matrix is a float value but my professor has it like that

```
### START YOUR CODE ###
X_dash = X * Y.reshape((Y.size, 1))
Q = cvxopt.matrix(np.dot(X_dash , X_dash.T) * 1)

### END YOUR CODE ###
print('Q = ', Q)


my output 
Q =  [ 0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00]
[ 0.00e+00  4.00e+00  0.00e+00 -6.00e+00 -8.00e+00]
[ 0.00e+00  0.00e+00  4.00e+00 -6.00e+00 -8.00e+00]
[ 0.00e+00 -6.00e+00 -6.00e+00  1.80e+01  2.40e+01]
[ 0.00e+00 -8.00e+00 -8.00e+00  2.40e+01  3.20e+01]

what I want
Q = [[ 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[ 0. 4. 0. -6. -8.]
[ 0. 0. 4. -6. -8.]
[ 0. -6. -6. 18. 24.]
[ 0. -8. -8. 24. 32.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try editing the matrix printing options:

```
>>> from cvxopt import matrix
>>> A = matrix(range(50), (5,10), 'd')
>>> print(A)
[ 0.000000e+00  2.000000e+00]
[ 1.000000e+00  3.000000e+00]
>>> from cvxopt import printing
>>> printing.options['dformat'] = '%d'
>>> print(A)
[0 2]
[1 3]
```

See [this matrix formatting guide for CVXOPT](https://cvxopt.org/userguide/printing.html).